# What's the difference between bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with Rails.

What's the difference between bootstrap and bootstrap-sprockets? Is sprockets the special version of bootstrap?

Answer (score 12):

The [github doc](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) for boostrap-sass explains it:

> bootstrap-sprockets and bootstrap should not both be included in
>   application.js.
>
> `bootstrap-sprockets` provides individual Bootstrap Javascript files
>   (alert.js or dropdown.js, for example), while `bootstrap` provides a
>   concatenated file containing all Bootstrap Javascripts.

Comment: so that if I am only need dropdown.js, only dropdown.js is downloaded which can save space. But I am wonder if dropdown.js ever minimized?

Comment: This is no longer true, if it ever was. bootstrap-sass docs say to use both: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @jrochkind That page still says to only `require` one in `application.js`. `@import`ing both would be appropriate for the `.scss`.